# Differential equation - annihilator method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can we solve this differential equation?
\begin{cases}
x''-y' = t+1,  \\
x'+y'-3x+y = 2t-1.
\end{cases}

Comment: Are the derivatives with respect to $t$?

Comment: $Answer: $
    $$\ x = c_1 +  c_2e^t+c_3e^{-3t}-\frac{1}{6}t^2- \frac{14}{9}t $$
  $$\ y = 3c_1 + \frac{17}{19} + c_2e^t - 3c_3e^{-3t}-\frac{1}{2}t^2-\frac{4}{3}t $$
But i dont know how to solve this

Answer (score 1):

You can apply Laplace transform operator on both equations transforming the differential system into an algebric system which can be solved with usual tecniques. Then the solution has to be antitransformed to obtain the required function that satisfies the differential system.

Answer (score 0):

HINT to solve:

$$
\begin{cases}
x''(t)-y'(t)=t+1\\
x'(t)+y'(t)-3x(t)+y(t)=2t-1
\end{cases}
$$

Use Laplace transform:

$$
\begin{cases}
s^2\text{X}(s)-sx(0)-x'(0)-s\text{Y}(s)-y(0)=\frac{1+s}{s^2}\\
s\text{X}(s)-x(0)+s\text{Y}(s)-3\text{X}(s)+\text{Y}(s)=\frac{2-s}{s^2}
\end{cases}
$$

so, we get:

- $$\text{X}(s)=\frac{\frac{1+s}{s^2}+sx(0)+x'(0)+s\text{Y}(s)+y(0)}{s^2}$$
- $$\text{Y}(s)=\frac{\frac{2-s}{s^2}-s\text{X}(s)+x(0)+3\text{X}(s)}{1+s}$$